# How do I get a given profile's default RecordType for Opportunity?

Tags: apex, force.com, record-type

The use case is when a user goes Personal Setup > My Personal Information > Record Type selection and checks the box for the default to be selected automatically when a record is created.

In this case, the Record Type Id does not come through on the URL. But on the page, I need to know the Record Type to do some field pre-population.

How do I get this default Record Type Id?

Comment: Your question is unclear. What do you mean by disable the record type selector on the left nav? Where, in setup, on a VF page, on a record? Are you talking about the sidebar, what left nav?

Comment: clarified the post for you

Comment: More clarification needed, how are you trying to do field pre-population, with JS in a button, with a VF page? The record type id does not come through on which record URL, the new button?

Comment: Record Type is normally a function of the Profile assigned to a User for a particular Object. In most cases, a different VF page will be displayed that's dependant on the User's Profile.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The closest I can get is the default record type for the current user:

```
//find all Opportunity record types
List<Schema.RecordTypeInfo> infos = Schema.SObjectType.Opportunity.RecordTypeInfos;
Id defaultRecordTypeId;

//check each one
for (Schema.RecordTypeInfo info : infos) {
  if (info.DefaultRecordTypeMapping) {
    defaultRecordTypeId = info.RecordTypeId;
  }
}

//here is the default Opportunity RecordType Id for the current user
System.debug(defaultRecordTypeId);
```

Comment: Code is not valid. You might want to finalize it ...

Comment: Code is not clear, what is rti?

Answer (score 10):

Got it....

```
if (ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('RecordType') == null) {
    Schema.DescribeSObjectResult describeOpp = Schema.SObjectType.Opportunity;    
    List<Schema.RecordTypeInfo> rtInfos = describeOpp.getRecordTypeInfos();
    for(Schema.RecordTypeInfo rtInfo : rtInfos) {
        if(rtInfo.isDefaultRecordTypeMapping()) {               
            ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().put('RecordType', rtInfo.getRecordTypeId());
            break;
        }
    }
    }
      String recordRT = ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('RecordType');
```

Comment: Of course!  I appreciate your helpfulness!

Comment: The following solution does not work for me. I have user for which only one record type is available and this solution returns master record type, which is unavailable for him, leading to INSUFFICIENT PRIVILEGES error. The solution however is quite simple. You just need to switch `rtInfo.isDefaultRecordTypeMapping()` to `rtInfo.isAvailable()`. That worked for me.